# Which books influenced the game Halo?

Tags: inspiration, halo

I read this [post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-much-did-larry-nivens-ringworld-inspire-the-halo-game-franchise) about the *Ringworld* series, but am curious about the main influences. I just started reading the *Forever War* and am reminded a lot about Halo; also, I read once that *Starship Troopers* was a big influence. Did either of these influence the original *Halo* plot? What were the main influences?

Comment: I'm giving this a +1 to offset the -1; it seems reasonably well-scoped and conforms sufficiently with the most recent decision I can find about "influence" questions, here: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1950/shouldnt-this-question-be-closed-as-off-topic/1954#1954

Comment: @JimmyShelter So a list of stories about the end of humanity is a no-no, but a list of stories with similarities to "Halo" is a yes-yes? I'm never going to understand the Rule Against List Questions.

Comment: @user14111 - I would guess because of the scope of the answer. Halo influence is going to be arguably a small group. The "end of world" is going to invite extended discussion and argument about "What about book X", and "Why not book Y", where you would have people arguing about the intent and scope of a massive amount of literature.

Comment: @JohnP has it right; this question has established that by having a definitive and authorative answer, the end-of-world question is open-ended (also note that this question was *not* "similarities" to Halo but was explicitly *influences* on Halo).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [wiki entry for Halo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_%28series%29):

1. *Ringworld* (Niven) and the Culture Series (Iain Banks, particularly *Consider Phlebias* and *Excession*) gave rise to the ringworld concept
2. *Armor* (John Steakley) - Sense of hopelessness by fighting the same war again and again
3. *The Vang* (Christopher Rowley) - The engulfing alien incursion, basis for The Flood. (Possibly also influenced the name of the Master Chief)
4. Speculation that the SPARTAN program and design of the Covenant drones was influenced by *Ender's Game* (Orson Scott Card)
5. Bungie has acknowledged the film *Aliens* (James Cameron) as a cinematic influence

Also, a report by Roger Travis published in *The Escapist* compares the *Halo* series with the Latin epic *Aenid* by Virgil.

Answer (score -1):

Biggest inspiration
StarShip Troopers:
 - Powered armor
 - A global governing body bordering on fascism (Colonial insurrection)
 - A vast military with no enemy to fight until the arrival of the Bugs/Covenant
 - Both Halo and SS had a soldier named Jenkins
 - The Bugs and the Flood